# Angular Ng file Upload Model : Abort function is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

Am using the following module https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload and it has well documented except for aborting the upload process.  During uploading the files, The code for **cancel the upload** is not working fine. 
Am getting error that says 'abort is not a function' and I do not know how to apply the abort() function to cancel the upload process.

I dont know what i missed here, Could anyone give me some idea on why? or any suggestion please.

My html

```
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <h4>Upload on file select</h4>

    <button ngf-select="uploadFiles($files)" multiple 
            accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*">Select Files</button>

    <span class="progress" ng-show="progress >= 0">
        <div style="width:{{progress}}%" ng-bind="progress + '%'"></div>
    </span>
    {{errorMsg}}

    <button ng-click="cancelUpload()">Cancel</button>

</body>
```

JS(Angular)

```
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {

var upload = "";

    $scope.uploadFiles = function (files) {
        $scope.files = files;
        if (files && files.length) {
            upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                data: {
                    files: files
                },
                resumeSize: function() {return promise;}
            }).then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0) {
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                }
            }, function (evt) {
                $scope.progress = 
                    Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    };


    $scope.cancelUpload = function(files){   // here is my cancel program
    console.log("Cancelling");
     upload.abort();              // this 'abort()' is not working as mentined
    }
```

Comment: Change the code to `upload = Upload.upload(...); upload.then(...);`

Comment: @danial Thanks a lot!!  it working fine..